# Error making disk image

Tags: disk

I am sorry if I am repeating someone's question, but I really couldn't find this one out there.

I am trying to make an image of my raspberry's microSD0, but I get this message:

"Error allocating space or disk image file: File too large (g-io-error-quark, 0)"

How do I solve it?

Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: What file system are you trying to save the disk image on?

Comment: I am trying to make an image from the whole disk, no just one partition. One of them is FAT the other is Ext4.

Comment: I know that. I mean where are you trying to save the image to? Some file systems will not allow files to be stored on them if the individual files are too large. For example, one cannot store an ISO image on a fat 32 file system if the image is bigger than 2 GB, even if the fat 32 file system has much more than 2 GB of free space.

Comment: I am trying to save in my own SSD, it is a FAT32 partition, but even when I try in the system, which is ext4, it fails. There is more than 100 GB in both. I didn't know I cannot save an image bigger than that, which file system should I use?

Comment: Hmm, IDK. Try NTFS if possible?

Comment: sure, just a moment.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!